# Validate a form against a formset in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a formset with three forms that the user inputs. Next to this, I have another form with one field that I want to validate against the fields inputted in the formset. Views.py looks something like:

```
FormSet = formset_factory(Form1, formset=BaseFormSet, extra=3)
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='first_form')
    form2 = Form2(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        # do something with the data
        pass
else:
    formset = FormSet(prefix='first_form')
    target_shoe_form = TargetShoeForm()
return render(request, 'my_template.html', {
    'formset': formset,
    'form2': form2,
})
```

Is there a way to validate `Form2` against the values in my `Formset`? As currently above they only validate internally, not against each other. Or, is it necessary to either nest the singleton form inside the formset, or nest the formset in the singleton form somehow? Thanks!

Update on validation:

`Form1` has two fields, and rendered three times as part of a formset. `Form2` has one field. When the user submits, I want to check that `Form2`'s field is distinct from any of the values submitted in `Form1`

Comment: Can you give some more detail about how the validation is supposed to work, and how the fields depend on each other?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for looking, just updated.